# Formulas to calculate the number of inversions for a permutation of n length: (help solving)

Tags: matrices, permutations

While reading Donald Knuth's "Sorting and Searching" I have come across a table of inversions which lists the numbers of inversions $k$ for a number of permutations of lengths $n$ (varying from 1 to 6).

There is a zigzag line which separates $I_{n}(n-1)$ from $I_{n}(n)$ as $n$ increases from 1 to 6 down the table.

So, while under the zigzag line the author has provided a formula which the printed numbers satisfy:

$I_{n}(k) = I_{n}(k - 1) + I_{n - 1}(k), \;for\; k < n$.

This formula has provided me no issues. Using a pencil and paper I was able to get the same numbers which the table prints, e.g. $I_{5}(3) = 15$, $I_{6}(2) = 14$, and $I_{6}(3) = 29$. I have completed this formula for each number under the zigzag in the table.

The table can be found at the link: [inversion table](https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/chap5_9780201896855/elementLinks/015tab01_alt.jpg) listed at [book reference](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2243840)

Now, my issue becomes apparent during the next paragraph where the following is stated:
"(This relation does [i]not[/i] hold [i]above[/i] the zigzag line.) A more complicated argument (see exercise 14) shows that, in fact, we have the formulas

[Inversion Formulas](https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/chap5_9780201896855/elementLinks/equ-015-01_alt.jpg)"

(a hyperlink is inserted here because I could not find a way to insert column-major matrices using MathJax)

While using the formulas above I have found answers that are often $(1\;2)$ (change to column-major) or $(2\;3)$ (change to column-major).

Because the answers should be integers representing the numbers of permutations that have $k$ inversions and not matrices, I am left confused. Could someone help me find the correct answer to this problem?

Comment: @JeanMarie a row-major matrix $(1\;2)$ may be rearranged vertically as a column-major matrix

Comment: What I didn't understand is the term "-major" I am not used to ; now that I have seen the definition [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), it's fine.